# How do I refresh a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with bound `ItemsSource`:

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="grid"
    FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListGuards}"
    IsReadOnly="True">
```

Columns definition (One example):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
```

Code-behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<TableGuard> ListGuards { get; set; }
public C'tor(...) {
    ListGuards = new ObservableCollection<TableGuard>(s); //s = List<TableGuard>
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Submitting data:

```
private void submit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (list == null)
            list = new List<TableGuard>();

        TableGuard guard = new TableGuard();
        guard.FName = fName.Text;
        guard.LName = lName.Text;
        guard.Id = int.Parse(id.Text);
        guard.WorkPlace = workPlace.Text;
        guard.LastTraining = lastTraining.Text;
        guard.NextTraining = nextTraining.Text;
        guard.Birthday = birthDay.Text;
        guard.TrainingType = trainingType.Text;

        bool exists = false;
        foreach (var g in list)
            if (guard.Id == g.Id) {
                exists = true;
                break;
            }

        if (exists)
            MessageBox.Show("ID EXISTS!");
        else if (id.Text.Length < 9)
            MessageBox.Show("ID NEEDS TO BE 9 DIGITS!");
        else {
            if (isEdit) {
                jsonObj[selectedRow]["Id"] = guard.Id;
                jsonObj[selectedRow]["FName"] = guard.FName;
                jsonObj[selectedRow]["LName"] = guard.LName;
                jsonObj[selectedRow]["Birthday"] = guard.Birthday;
                jsonObj[selectedRow]["LastTraining"] = guard.LastTraining;
                jsonObj[selectedRow]["NextTraining"] = guard.NextTraining;
                jsonObj[selectedRow]["WorkPlace"] = guard.WorkPlace;
                jsonObj[selectedRow]["TrainingType"] = guard.TrainingType;
                File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj));
                Close();
            } else {
                list.Add(guard);
                File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list));
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I wish to refresh the `DataGrid` after I edit some data. How do I do it?

Comment: Are you trying to detect when the data has changed, i.e. in an event and then refresh, or simply how to refresh the grid after a change (and you know when this has happened)?

Comment: When you edit data it will be refreshed automatically iff you have INotify.. in place. show us more code and also check your columns definition

Comment: @Shane.CI just want to refresh, I know when the data changes

Comment: as I said, it should reflect on screen as you change it, show us your implementation of grid and changing data if its not.

Comment: how are you editing your data ?

Comment: @MudsEdited columns definition

Comment: @MudsSerializing & DeSerializing JSON

Comment: some  code to back that up will be great ..

Comment: where you are changing data and implementation of the property that you change,

Comment: show us your TableGuard object. submitting code makes no sense for your question, because ListGuards is not altered/changed

Comment: You can try CollectionView and Refresh function.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
grid.Items.Refresh();
```

I do wonder if this will work for your situation.

edit:spelling

Answer (score -2):

As you are using an `ObservableCollection`, your grid will update when an item is **added** or **removed** from the list.

However, if you are instantiating a new `ObservableCollection`, then your grid will not update, as your property does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your class and call the `PropertyChanged` event to update your grid:

```
private ObservableCollection<TableGuard> _ListGuards;

    public ObservableCollection<TableGuard> ListGuards
    {
        get { return _ListGuards; }
        set 
        { 
            _ListGuards = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ListGuards");
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

At the end of your **submit** method, you simply need to reset all of the items in the **ListGuards** list. Either call the `.Clear()` method and add the items to the collection or **instantiate** a new `ObservableCollection` after implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the property.

Comment: well changes will be notified as its an observable colln !

Comment: and datacontext is set after initialization and hence that should not be a problem

Comment: @Muds Like I mentioned in my answer, if he is **instantiating** a new `ObservableCollection` (`ListGuards = new ObservableCollection<TableGuard>(s);`), then the grid will not refresh unless the property implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, **or** the `DataContext` is set again. It's much easier to just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the property. Not to mention that you shouldn't be setting `this.DataContext = this;` anyway.

Comment: That's not correct am afraid, altho I agree that this.dataContext = this isn't the best way, But if the collection is instantiated before setting data context it should be ok ...

Comment: _I wish to refresh the DataGrid after I edit some data. How do I do it?_ @Muds You are absolutely correct, there is no problem in the constructor, however OP isn't having a problem in the constructor, he is asking how to update the binding to the `ObservableCollection` after he's changed some data. I am presuming that he is using the same method, which is instantiating a new `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: well its an observable collection I would hope it to work seamlessly in such cases unless someone screws it forcefully, let op come back with more code and see what it has ..

Answer (score -2):

your TableGuard class has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise it properly. And in your columnsdefinition of your datagrid you have to set the mode to TwoWay. if you add and remove items in your collection look at the other answer.

just for the downvote:

if you debug your code and in the row in your ctor

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

your Property ListGuards property is empty and you never use ListGuards.Add/Remove you should not see anything in your grid.

Comment: well I was not the firstone to downvote but if you read ans below and comments you wouldn't have has this question

Comment: with the code posted in the question may answer is right. i do it in all my projects. the code under Submitting data: is not relevant at all for the question because the itemssource collection is not altered in any way. so pls say what wrong with my answer?

Comment: assumptions? if you bind the itemsource to an autoproperty wpf is never notice if a new instance is set. so just add and remove would work (of course just with a ObservableCollection not with List or something) to "fill" the collection(or setting within the ctor). and even more when a datagrid should show editing changes then simply the bound object has to implement and raise INotifyPropertyChanged for the bound properties. so there are no assumption.

Comment: @blindmeis You are absolutely correct. Add and removing items will update the UI, however overwriting the collection will not. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is needed in this case. Until OP implements the interface and calls `ListGuards = new ObservableCollection<TableGuard>(s);` (assuming that **s** is also being updated) again in his submit method, I guess we'll be downvote stormed together.

Answer (score -2):

Android

in your Submitted method you either set ListGuard to list or simply add all the objects in ListGuard  collection